# json problem java

Tags: java, json

I have a something like this

```
String value={"name":"Michal","location":"unknown"}
```

I would like to get all elements using JSONOBJECT

Something like this doesn't work:

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(value);        
System.out.println(json.get("name"))
```

Comment: does not work how? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Post your stacktrace please, besides the string `value` is not proper java syntax.

Comment: `String value={"name":"Michal","location":"unknown"}` -- that can't possibly be right.

Comment: The `String value` isn't legal syntax - what do you actually have?

Answer (score 1):

I get this from server http://localhost:4567/resource.json
when I do value.toString() i excatly get what I wrote above.

I have got code:

```
in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(address).openStream());
//    fout = new FileOutputStream(budaPath + destination);

byte data[] = new byte[1024];
int count;
while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1)
{
    System.out.println(" "+data);
    //fout.write(data, 0, count);
}

String value = new String(data);
System.out.println(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method。

```
    JSONObject json=JSONObject.fromObject(object)
```

If it's have some exceptions.Pls paste them.

Comment: when  value.toString() I have got exacty:

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you defined your string variable correct?

```
String name = "Michal";
String location = "unknown";
String value="{\"name\":\"" + name + "\", \"location\":\"" + unknown + "\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem I think that the problem was with encoding now I use URLConnection and it works:

```
public class Json {
    public static JSONObject getJSON(String address) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, ParseException{

    URL url=new URL(address);
    URLConnection connection=url.openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    Scanner in=new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    while (in.hasNextLine()){
        sb.append(in.nextLine());
    }
    String value=sb.toString();
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(value);

    return json;

    }
}
```